# How to get use of the options in ngx-export-as

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, datatables, angular6

I'm new to angular, I have a datatable in which I display set of data and I'm exporting the table's data as pdf using ngx-export-as, everything is working fine however, in the pdf that gets downloaded it shows the sort arrows and some data that I don't need in my pdf, I've checked out the documentation using this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-export-as but it is not stating the options. I would appreciate if you can tell me how I can hide the sorting arrows and any other elements as well

employees.component.html

```
<button (click)="ExportAsPDF()" class="dropdown-item">PDF</button>
<table id="myTable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"></table>
```

employees.component.ts

```
exportAsConfigPdf: ExportAsConfig = {
    type: 'pdf',
    elementId: 'myTable',
    options: {
    }
}

ExportAsPDF(){
    this.exportAsService.save(this.exportAsConfigPdf, 'Employees Table').subscribe(() 
   => {});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

library options should be inside config.options object
https://github.com/wnabil/ngx-export-as#configuration